# Order of conjugacy classes.

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

Suppose $a \in G$ has $m$ conjugates, and $a^k$ has $n$ conjugates. Show that $n$ divides $m$.

Since order of the conjugacy class is $\left|G\right|\over\left|C_G(a)\right|$ where $C_G(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$, I know that eventually $\left|C_G(a^k)\right|\over\left|C_G(a)\right|$ has to be an integer in order for $n$ to divide $m$.
But I am not sure how to relate the order of the two centralizers here to show that $n$ divides $m$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $C_G(a)\leq C_G(a^k)$. The reason is simply if $x$ commutes with $a$, then $x$
$$xa^2=xaa=axa=aax=a^2x$$

By induction, you can show that $a^k$ commutes with $x$. Then the result follows.

Let me leave you an exercise. If $Gcd(k,|a|)=1$ then show that $C_G(a)=C_G(a^k)$.

Comment: I actually deduced this while waiting for an answer, so how I progressed was, first I showed $C_G(a)$ was a subgroup by showing it is closed under group operation and taking the inverse, then showed that any element in $C_G(a)$ will be in $C_G(a^k)$. Would that suffice?

Comment: If you show that $C_G(a)\leq C_G(a^k)$ then you can conclude by $$|G:C_G(a)|=|G:C_G(a^k)||C_G(a^k):C_G(a)|$$. Then $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: Is showing $C_G(a)$ is closed under multiplication and inverse and the fact that for every element $g \in G$ if $g \in C_G(a)$, then $g \in C_G(a^k)$ show that $C_G(a) \le C_G(a^k)$?

Comment: To solve this question, you are already suppoesd to know that $C_G(a)$ is a group. Without knowing this how can you talk about index of $C_G(a)$ ? and conjuacy classes ?

Comment: Yes I know that $C_G(a)$ is a group but I'm trying to show that $C_G(a) \le C_G(a^k)$ and I'm not sure what I stated suffices to show that